# What should I do with this user?

Tags: support, status-completed, new-users

There's a new user in [Google App Engine town](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine), a user[s] that is keep asking low quality questions with <strike>three</strike> four different accounts.

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/users/713233

https://stackoverflow.com/users/714526

https://stackoverflow.com/users/720100

https://stackoverflow.com/users/704153

I've flagged and downvoted him/her/them more than one time for different reasons, but I kind of feel that my -1 magic bullets are wasted for this kind of multiuser-user-<strike>three</strike>fourheaded-creature.

What should I do?
Save the downvotes and move on or KEEP him/her/them under my target?

**THE SEQUEL:**
raised from the ashes of the 3-4-6 headed-monster still confined in the dreaded [penalty box](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720100/ramprasad)..
[Here is again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787700/how-to-retrive-data-from-datastore-using-gwt-client-coding) with a brand [new account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/724992/ramprasad).

Comment: I didn't know that Hydra has wings.

Comment: that's [King Ghidorah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Ghidorah)

Comment: ah I see, that make sense. :-)

Comment: your graphical solicitation for upvotes worked... +1 from me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have merged them all (and 2 you missed ;p) into the most recent, and contacted them etc. Flagging for moderator attention is the preferred option here, note.

Comment: this should be tagged as [mission-complete]

Comment: wow, it's not defeated at all and I don't have any coins to continue.

Comment: (That new closing and merging was quick, @Marc!)

Comment: @Arjan k, I'll admit he is annoying me now.

Comment: Can't you put IP ban? Or does he have different IP every time?

Answer (score 5):

Flag one of his questions for `Moderator Attention` and request a merge of all 4 accounts. And after that, just keep downvoting. The system is designed to handle low-quality posters like this, but the important thing is that his accounts need to be merged to trigger the dreaded `Sorry we're no longer accepting questions from this account` message.